# Meteor manipulate Mongodb data from function

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have loaded a dataset in my collection called Plants. Here's an example of a plant:

```
{
"_id": "zGdXzfFTAzhrhCvqE",
"Plant": "Carrot",
"Companions": ["Beetroot", "Dandelion", "Rose"]
}
```

I need to update my collection so each companion is a record (has an _id), so first I need to check if the companion already has an _id, but I can't seem to get the syntax right.

```
  //why does'nt this work?
  var com = Plants.find({"Plant": "Thyme"});
  console.log("id: " + com._id); //returns undefined, even though it exists   in the collection

  //this works 
  Plants.find({}).forEach(function(plant){
    var companions = plant.Companions;
    console.log(companions[0]);  //prints out the first plantname in the array

    //here I need to check if the plant is already in the collection
    for(var i = 0; i < companions.length; i++){
      var com_plante = Plants.findOne(companions[i]);
      //this writes out undefined
      console.log("com_plante: " + com_plante._id + " " + com_plante.Plant);
    } 
  }
```

What's wrong with my syntax?

Answer (score 1):

Use `findOne` instead:

```
var com = Plants.findOne({"Plant": "Thyme"});
```

`findOne` returns a single data item matching the selector. Conversely, `find` returns a *cursor* that iterates through matching items. Obviously, the cursor itself doesn't have the same properties as a single items. The cursor can be converted into an array of items via `fetch()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Your second search (inside the loop) is based on a string but you're using the shorthand for searching by `_id`:

```
var com_plante = Plants.findOne(companions[i]);
```

When `.find()` or `.findOne()` see a single scalar argument they only check the `_id` key for a match.

Use:

```
var com_plante = Plants.findOne({Plant: companions[i]});
```